# Connection String in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, I saw some of web application they are maintaing the connection string in drives of the system, i mean they are storing the connection string in system drives like c:, D: drive. how can i store the connection string in the system drives. please help me.

Comment: That's was a not good enough application example. Better use web.config `ConnectionStrings` section.

Comment: what about for intronet application Mr. Yuriy Rozhovetskiy

Comment: This advice not depends on application type. You'll save a lot of time for implementing and much more time for support your application if you will not store connection strings in unobvious place.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the configSource attribute for the connectionStrings element? You can then store config settings in separate config files, **relative** to your app folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.80).aspx

There's a related Stack Overflow topic here:

[.NET Config Files configSource outside the application directory folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569117/net-config-files-configsource-outside-the-application-directory-folder)