# Is there a way to store connection strings in a central location other than machine.config

Tags: .net, configuration, connection-string, app-config

I am currently trying to ease the configuration hell that exists on our client-servers.  We have something like 8 applications who each have their own connection string info, and we were hoping to store connection strings in a central location to make our poor support team's life easier.  However, I have been asked to avoid doing this in machine.config because (1) we are frequently not the only third party on servers at client sites and apparently (this concern shouldn't matter as long as we name things reasonably, but that's a different fight I've got to fight) (2) there are a couple of clients who don't want us to touch machine.config (for what I assume are invalid reasons, but I don't get paid to worry about such things).

Unfortunately, linking to an external file via the configSource attribute of  doesn't work unless the external file resides in or below the directory the application configuration file resides in.

Is there any way to do this that won't involve me doing something like copying connection string information into configuration files at application startup?

Comment: Your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569117/net-config-files-configsource-outside-the-application-directory-folder

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in the Registry.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in an active directory and then retrieve it with a query. Or you can try this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66569/How-to-store-shared-app-settings-and-connection-st