# Copy settings from one Web.config to another except AppSettings and ConnectionStrings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible, through code, to copy settings from one Web.config file to another (except AppSettings and ConnectionStrings)?

I have a situation where a single MVC3 project has been deployed to multiple servers in different locations. There is an auto-updater on all of these that will pull in the latest version. Typically when this would run, it would only overwrite the application folders and NOT the Web.config file.

I just upgraded the project to MVC4. This changes basically everything in the Web.config file except the AppSettings and ConnectionStrings. All of the installations of this project would have slightly different values here.

How would I go about writing some code that will update the Web.config file, but preserve all of the AppSettings and ConnectionStrings?

Answer (score 1):

.NET provides ways to get configuration from other config file. Refer this article:http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx

Basically, you can use "configSource" attribute to define which config file to refer. Note that the configuration file should be in same directory. if not, Refer here to solve the problem. [.NET Config Files configSource outside the application directory folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569117/net-config-files-configsource-outside-the-application-directory-folder)