# Splitting the configuration file leads to exception in System.Configuration.dll

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, app-config

I have a MVC .NET application. The solution contains the application itself and a unit test project, which also contains integration tests (including data layer tests which need a database connection).

I decided to put the connection strings for both project in a separate configuration file. I copied the content of the `<connectionStrings>` tag into a new file, and used the configSource attribute in the Web.config file of the web project and in the app.config file of the test project. The web project debugs and runs just like before. The test project cannot be debugged, it exits with

> 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.resources.dll'
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

When I try to run it, all tests fail. They pass when I use the original version of the app.config file.

This is the version of app.config which works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TumorModelsDB" connectionString="Data source=tsql2; Initial Catalog=TumorModelle; User Id=anonymized; Password=anonymized;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AzaraIntegrationTest" connectionString="Data Source=tsql2;Initial Catalog=AzaraIntegrationTest;User Id=anonymized; Password=anonymized;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And this is the version which does not work (litteraly the same as the web.config with which the other project works):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config" />
</configuration>
```

The (complete) new ConnectionStrings.config file is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TumorModelsDB" connectionString="Data source=tsql2; Initial Catalog=TumorModelle; User Id=anonymized; Password=anonymized;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AzaraIntegrationTest" connectionString="Data Source=tsql2;Initial Catalog=AzaraIntegrationTest;User Id=anonymized; Password=anonymized;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The content of the ConnectionStrings.config file is exactly the same as the old content of the connection strings tag. There is no typo in the filename in the configSource attribute. The ConnectionStrings.config file is present in the test project (it is not a link from the web project). The Build Action is set to Content, and Copy to Output is Do not copy. I am running out of ideas where to look for the source of the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

Despite the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693705/1983448) saying that the correct setting is "Do not copy", setting it to "Always copy" solved the problem. Now the project runs and debugs as expected.

The web project also runs properly when its file is set to Always copy. This was useful when I replaced the included file with a link to the web project's connection settings file, as I had intended from the beginning.

The step-by-step solution: On the config file, choose Properties. In the Properties Window, change the value of the Copy on output setting to Always copy.