# Unable to open configSource file that was added as link

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, web-config

In my MVC application I use external config files to keep clean web.config. Some files are common and I added them to project as link from one location. For those files I set Copy option to Copy always and those files are copied to destination folder and I see them. But when I try to open home page in the browser I see "Unable to open configSource file" error. When I remove links to files and just add them (no link) everything works good. Any idea what may cause this error?

Comment: This is not supported.

Comment: Oh, really? I read many articles where this technic was described. The only acent was on Copy option, it should be Copy always or Copy if newer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I found what was the issue. When use Copy always, files are copied to bin folder. But files are searched in the virtual directory not in the bin. So I added post build task which copies files to correct destination.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the case of connectionStrings.config, it must be in the same folder as web.config to work correctly: https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

Answer (score 9):

After trying the xcopy solution, which failed, the follow worked for me:

Right click the cstrings.config, go to `Properties`.

Set the property `Copy to Output Directory` value to `Copy always`

Comment: I had a issue with log4net config file and this helped me, thanks! Steps: right click log4net.config and select [Properties], lastly set [Copy to Output] file property => Always Copy

Answer (score 8):

I added the post build event as suggested. But the exact steps are:

1. Right click on the project and navigate to properties
2. Click on the Build Events tab
3. In the **Post-build event command line:** box I added:

**xcopy /s "$(ProjectDir)\bin\Config" "$(ProjectDir)\Config"**

Answer (score 6):

I suffered from the same problem. In my case, config file's 'Build Action' property was the cause.
( Right click on the config file > Properties > Build Action )

The 'Build Action' value was set to 'None'. After I changed it to 'Content', the problem sovled.
( I am not sure if it was 'a Visual Studio's bug' or 'my click-by-mistake' that made it set to 'None'.

Answer (score 5):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408867/2240453 
Long story short: You can add

```
<connectionStrings configSource="bin\Connections.config">  
</connectionStrings>
```

to differentiate configuration (deploy/release so debug/deploy version) You can add [transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) . It's quite handy to use them anyway.

(Yes, i know the topic is solved, but maybe someone will find this information useful as I did)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the config file > Properties. Set the setting like below screenshot

[image]