# Live Unit Testing "Unable to open configSource file" error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, live-unit-tests, shared-config

I have a Helper project **H**, with a config file that is to be used as a shared *configSource* file from other projects. 
The code in file (*SharedConnectionString.config*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myConn" connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username; password=PW;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have a test project **A** that have it's own *App.config* and the *SharedConnectionString.config* added as file link

Config files in project **A**:

[image: Config files in project **A**]

On the *App.config* I have:

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="SharedConnectionStrings.config" />
```

Now, the test project compiles, the unit tests run successfully but the Live Unit Test feature from Visual Studio presents an error:

[image: Live Unit Testing error]

I tried the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186420/unable-to-open-configsource-file-that-was-added-as-link#39768847) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186420/unable-to-open-configsource-file-that-was-added-as-link#50981657). None of there fixed the problem.

Opened an [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/635096/live-unit-testing-unable-to-open-configsource-file.html) with Microsoft to see if help comes from somewhere..