# Using external config file for connection strings in multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, connection-string, app-config

I want to know if there is a better way to use connection strings in external files in my solution, since my solution has 8 separate projects, all using the same connection strings. According to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files#using-external-configuration-files

using an external file (for connection strings) is trivial, and can be easily done (using something like `configSource="connections.config`). However, in order to make this work, We have to follow these guidelines:

1. The external file has to exist within the project folder
2. The external file has to have the property "CopyToOutputFolder" set to true

In my case, this *can* be done, but it's problematic to manage this throughout all 8 projects, especially if I need to add a new connection string, change one of the settings (target database, username, password), or when I need to add a new project.

--**FYI:** each of these projects are web jobs that are deployed to an Azure server. Adding a new web job for a new feature, new utility, etc., or removing an old web job for any number of reasons is not uncommon. This solution is constantly changing, which adds to the difficulty of managing these settings within each project separately. Also, connection string management on the production server is not problematic, since each web job inherits these connection strings from the parent app service.

I would like to know if any of the following is possible;

1. Can I use a separate file that is **NOT** within the project folder for the connection strings?
2. Can I load connection strings dynamically (at run-time) into the configuration manager? (one note on this - I know this is *possible*, but I need to be able to do it without affecting the underlying app.config file)
3. Is there another *type* of `ConfigurationManager` that is commonly used to load these connection strings into the solution, that will meet my requirements?

Comment: Take a look on the last answer (from alexs) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569117/net-config-files-configsource-outside-the-application-directory-folder.

Comment: Yeah that's using the AppSettings unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is over a year old, I thought an up-to-date answer would be useful for any Windows desktop coders wanting to reference connection strings outside the project folder's app.config etc.  This would be useful for sharing 1 config file for multiple projects, having to only change connection string in 1 centralised file.

The basics of telling App.Config to use a different file for connection strings, is straightforward; however, .NET appears **NOT** to be able to parse this external file, if it is either **NOT** in the project's root folder, or a subfolder(s) within that project.  Let's see this by looking at the most basic example:

in the project's App.config, within the `<configuration>` tag, use the code below ('configSource' points to another file to read the connection strings):

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ExternalConnectionStrings.config"/>
</configuration>
```

Create `ExternalConnectionStrings.config`, with the following code:

```
<connectionStrings>
<clear/>
    <add name = "ConnString1"
         connectionString = "Server=myServer;Trusted_Connection=True;Database=myDB;Persist Security Info=false"/>
    <add name = "ConnString2"
         connectionString = "Server=tcp:azureserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=AzureDB;User ID=**;Password=**;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=false"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Save this config file in the same folder as your project's `App.config` and mark this file's property to 'Copy to Output Directory' or 'Copy if newer'.

This is the 'textbook' way of referring to connection strings from another file other than `App.config`.  However, this may not be that useful: how to have this external file in a completely different folder from the project folder?

To do this, copy that same `ExternalConnectionStrings.config` to a folder **OUTSIDE** the project or solution folder, eg. `C:\ConnectionStringsFolder\`.  **REMOVE** this config file from the project folder where we previously copied/created it (otherwise the following instructions will not work).

Keep `App.config` the same (making sure the ExternalConnectionStrings.config is not present in the project folder).  Use the Windows `mklink` command to associate `ExternalConnectionStrings.config` to an external folder, with the following command prompt command:

```
mklink ExternalConnectionStrings.config C:\ConnectionStringsFolder\ExternalConnectionStrings.config
```

Windows should return with a 'symbolic link created for....'; make sure you did **NOT** have that particular config file present in the project folder where `app.config` sits.

You should see the `ExternalConnectionStrings.config` listed within eg. Visual Studio; make sure you mark this to COPY to the output folder (I use 'Copy if newer', which will pick up any changes to the external config file *ONLY* after a rebuild of the project).

This answers Matt Spinks' question 1; for question 2, the following method will return all connection strings found within the external file (as pointed to by `App.config`):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Configuration;

    static void GetConnectionStrings()
            {
                ConnectionStringSettingsCollection cStringsSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

                if (cStringsSettings != null)
                {
                    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cstrings in cStringsSettings)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(cstrings.Name);
                        Debug.WriteLine(cstrings.ConnectionString);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is currently working in Visual Studio 2019, with .NET Core 3.1, a WPF application, on Windows 10.

Comment: Great solution.  Ultimately I think I'll go with editing Machine.Config to provide a centralized source for common connection strings.  Any solution that uses some of the "forgotten" features of NTFS gets a +1 though.  Your solution will be great for anyone who can access the file system but can't own the machine configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of dotnet you are using, however if you are using dotnet core the application configuration can be sourced from environment variables.

I think this could solve your problem because you don't need to track any additional files between your projects and in my opinion makes a lot of sense because any secure data would not be visible to any developer or be stored in any repository. Only devops would know about it when they set it initially. Also this gets your closer to the 12 factor app https://12factor.net/.

To use this make sure that your Startup.cs file includes a section to load the environment variables such as

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

[dotnet core Environment Variable cnfiguration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#environment-variables-configuration-provider)

You can probably create a bat file to set everything initially

```
setx connection_string="Server=xxxxxxxxx" /M
```

This will create your environment variables and set the values you specity.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks @Leo. I'll give it a go. But I am using .NET 4.6. Sorry I didn't mention that.